# Adding a separate list as tool tips for an asp.net drop down list

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I can find many examples of how to add a tool tip to a drop down list that is the list item itself, i.e. it is to long to be displayed in the list, but that is not what I I need.

What I need is the following;

I have a drop down list that has a list of numbers from 1 to ?? For each number there is a corresponding text item. What I am trying to do is if you expand the list and mouse over a number I need the text item from the separate list to be displayed as a tool tip. Example I mouse over the number 1 and the tool tip display's 'Section 1'.

Is this even possible? If someone can point in the right direction it would be great.

Oh and I am doing this in VB.Net if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding another dropdown to the drop-down, with text instead of a link. If that makes sense, don't know if the framework you use allows it though =D.
If it isn't a very important feature, you could probably do it with an annotation

Comment: so something like a multi-column dropdownlist?

Comment: If that is what you want, that is probably the least expensive solution, adding another dropdown for every entry would be super expensive for a dropdown.